# What are allowable values for allocate_tokens_for_keyspace in cassandra.yaml?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

Cassandra 3.0 added a new option to optimize the load across nodes, `allocate_tokens_for_keyspace`, in cassandra.yaml with default value `KEYSPACE`.

- Does a specific keyspace need to be provided?
- What does the default value `KEYSPACE` do?
- If it needs to be specific, how do I specify multiple keyspaces for a
  node?

Experimenting with different values I have been able to put random strings and comma separated lists in when adding a node and the new node joins the cluster but there are no useful messages in the debug log saying whether the value is valid or not. I have searched but found no documentation explaining allowable values for `allocate_tokens_for_keyspace`.

Answer (score 0):

More info about allocate_tokens_for_keyspace could be found at below link.

https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/token-allocation-algorithm

Also you could not have multiple keyspace value in "allocate_tokens_for_keyspace". you could only have one keyspace name from which new node token range should be created during Bootstrap.